# Problemas con controlador update laravel

Tags: laravel, oracle

tengo problemas para para actualizar un formulario cuando quiero actualizar un registro en mi base 
de datos pero tengo que pasarle los parametros hasta mi controlador pero estoy viendo que no me estan llegando hasta mi controlador por que cuando hago un dd del $request no  me los esta llevando los valores de mi formulario no se si es que tengo mi formulario malo o que puede ser

este es mi formulario que quiero actualizar

```
<div class="content">
                        @foreach($info as $info)

                            <form method="POST"
                                  action="{{url('editar_datos_post/'.$info->id_enlace.'/'.$info->periodo)}}">
                                @csrf
                                @method('POST')

                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <label for="inputEmail4">Proveedor</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$info->proveedor}}"
                                               id="proveedor">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Desc_enlace</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc_enlace"
                                           value="{{$info->desc_enlace}}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="inputEmail4">Id_enlace</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$info->id_enlace}}"
                                               id="id_enlace">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="inputPassword4">Valor_pago</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$info->valor_pago}}"
                                               id="valor_pago">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="inputEmail4">Periodo</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$info->periodo}}"
                                               id="periodo">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Actualizar</button>
                            </form>
                        @endforeach
```

esta es mi ruta

```
Route::POST('editar_datos_post/{id_enlace}/{periodo}',[
    'as'=>'editar_datos_post',
    'uses'=>'editar_datos@editar_post'
]);
```

este es mi controlador donde quiero hacer mi update en el cual tengo el problema

```
 public function editar_post(Request $request)
    {
//
        \DB::beginTransaction();

        dd($request);

        importar::where('id_enlace', '=', $request->id_enlace)->where('periodo', '=', $request->periodo)->update([

            'periodo' => $request->periodo,
            'desc_enlace' => $request->desc_enlace,
            'id_enlace' => $request->id_enlace,
            'valor_pago' => $request->valor_pago,
            'periodo' => $request->periodo,
        ]);


        return back()->with('messagee', 'El REGISTRO FUE ACTUALIZADO CORRECTAMENTE');
    }
```

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, ¿cuál es la falla de este código?

Comment: El problema que tengo es ala hora de realizar la consulta para que me actualice el registro mi problema esta en mi controlador ya que nunca lo habia intentado con 2 variables identificar un registro y actualizarlo no se si esta bien asi como lo llevo

Comment: Pregunto: ¿Ya lo probaste?, ¿qué resultado te dio?

Comment: si me dio este error Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::update(), 0 passed in

Answer (score 1):

El método `update` del *query builder* de Laravel necesita recibir valores como argumento en sus parentesis (por esa razón te dice que tiene muy pocos argumentos con los cuales trabajar).

Es decir, que le indiques en una estructura de vector asociativo las columnas con los valores que deseas actualizar.

Por ejemplo a tu consulta, después del `where` le tendrías que agregar algo así:

```
DB::table('fcm_enl_ter_fact')->where('ID_ENLACE', $id_enlace)
                             ->where('PERIODO', $periodo)
                             ->update(["columna1" => valor1, "columnaN" => valorN]);
```

Por cierto para tratar de mantener un poco mas legible tu código, puedes evitar el uso del *facade* `DB` para invocar a la tabla y en su lugar acceder al modelo que sea la representación de la misma quedando así:

```
Model::where('ID_ENLACE', $id_enlace)
      ->where('PERIODO', $periodo)
      ->update(["columna1" => valor1, "columnaN" => valorN]);
```

Comment: Si ahi modifique mi pregunta amigo pero estoy viendo que no me actualiza al parecer no me esta mandando los datos de mi formulario a mi controlador

Comment: Si en vez de POST colocas PUT?

Answer (score 0):

Ya revise bien el codigo

el problema es que todos los inputs los tienes sin el atributo name=''

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$info->proveedor}}" id="proveedor">
```

Intenta probando colocar

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$info->proveedor}}" id="proveedor" name="proveedor">
```

el atributo 'id' es para usarlo en el front e identificar ese input dentro del DOM ya sea con JS o con jquery por el contrario la variable Name es como se indentificara el input una vez el formulario haya sido enviado

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp